# Adding resources to an existing assembly

Tags: .net, reflection

I have a COM Interop DLL that I'm automatically generating from an existing COM DLL, using `tlbimp`.  What I need is to add Details to the DLL's Properties dialog for file version, copyright info, etc.

I found [some sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblycopyrightattribute.aspx#Y1166) that uses the `AssemblyBuilder.SetCustomAttribute()` API to dynamically set `AssemblyCopyrightAttribute`, etc.

However, the `AssemblyBuilder` instance in use comes from `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly()`, which appears to only create **new** assemblies. (Indeed, whenever I try that code with my DLL name, it deletes my DLL and creates a new one.)

Is there any way to get an instance of `AssemblyBuilder` for an existing assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you're fundamentally looking for the wrong solution.  What you see in explorer's Details tab is actually an *unmanaged* resource.  The C# compiler auto-generates one from the assembly attributes (/win32res compiler option), this of course does not happen when you create an interop assembly.  Or for that matter try to create one with an AssemblyBuilder.

To make this work, you first have to disassemble the interop library with ildasm.exe /out.  Next, you have to create a version resource, best done with a C++ project.  Use the resource editor to add a Version resource.  After building you get a .res file.  Then use ilasm.exe to re-create the interop library, using the /resource option to get the .res file embedded.

I gave you the 100 miles per hour version, this is hard to automate.

Comment: Thank you for clearing up my confusion between managed and unmanaged resources.  My existing COM DLL already has a version resource, so this technique was very straightforward.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to jump the many hoops Hans mentions just to add an unmanaged resource to a PE file. Create a version resource [in-memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647001.aspx) — it's not very difficult — and use Win32 [`BeginUpdateResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648030.aspx)&co. to add this resource to the .exe file produced by `tlbimp`.

Comment: This solution isn't appropriate for me because the managed DLL in question doesn't even have any source code, so there's nowhere to do the in-memory version resource creation, nor any Win32 calls.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood me. My solution does the same thing as Hans': adds a new unmanaged version resource to an assembly. The inputs are an assembly file and version data and the output is a modified assembly file containing specified version data.

Comment: I guess I do misunderstand.  Where would I do the in-memory version resource creation, and the calling of BeginUpdateResource et al?  Are you suggesting I write a utility to do this?  Beyond defining resources, Hans' solution requires no additional programming, which is pretty appealing...

Comment: Your remarks about `AssemblyBuilder` seemed to imply that you have some kind of program which is generating the interop assembly. Version-related code could be bolted onto it. If this is not the case a purely scripted solution might be easier to implement.

Comment: Ah I see the confusion; thanks for sticking around to resolve it.  I'm generating the interop assembly with [tlbimp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx.aspx), so no code there.  And I only ever used `AssemblyBuilder` in trying out that code sample I referenced.